# how to show a txt file when clicking the button in c#

Tags: c#

I'm new for c#, and i need to write a programme with a button (clicking it to show a .txt file)
could someone give me some idea or may be an example code

thanks

Comment: do u want to give option to download .txt file to users ?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET Web Forms? MVC? Windows App? Not clear from the question.

Comment: While we understand you're new. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Your questin is too unspecific. You should have a go at creating an application, and when you encounter any problem you can ask a specific question about that. There are plenty of examples on the web on how to do the separate parts of your task (I.E. handle button events, reading files, displaying text) that can help you on the way.

Comment: _"clicking it to show a .txt file"_ Do you mean you want to open a notepad?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer for WinForms:

Place `textBox` named `tbBrowser` and `Button` named `bBrowse` on form. Double-click button to create button `Click` handler. Place the following code in the handler:

```
    String filename = @"C:\Temp\1.txt";
    using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        String content = rdr.ReadToEnd();
        tbBrowser.Text = content;
    }
```

See [StreamReader documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx) for reference.

Answer for ASP.NET would be completely different, but it's unlikely you are asking about that (at least word `program` in question makes me think so)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said if you wanted to use winforms, wpf or something else.  Anyway, the code below will work for winforms - just add a textbox to your form:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Create reader & open file
        using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"C:\myfile.txt"))
        {            
            textBox1.Text += tr.ReadToEnd();                
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating windows form appln add a button to you form

double click the button

and in the method write the following code

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = "give your path";
            // or you can give your path in app.config and read from app.config if you want
            // to change the path .

```
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
            do
            {
                string textLine = reader.ReadLine() + "\r\n";

            }
            while (reader.Peek() != -1);
            reader.Close();
        }

    }
```